# I can't create a c# script in unity editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPZwy.png) So Normally you can do right-click > create> c# script but this time it didn't work, in my old project, (the version on the old project is "2021.1.5f1" ) I can create a c# script but in the last version, I can't, I thought it may be because the project was Universal Render Pipeline so I tried the same on a 3D project and the results were the same. Can anyone help?

Comment: Id say its gone off the top of the screen

Answer (score 1):

1. Try creating the script from your IDE. E.g. in vs code you can create a new file in the file explorer and name it "yourFile.cs" and it should create a C# script that will also appear in the unity editor.
2. In your attached photo it looks like there is some sort of overlay glitch or something. To fix that try installing a recommended (LTS) version of Unity in your Unity Hub.

For now the first thing would be your easiest and quickest fix/workaround.